# RMarkdown flexdashboard vertical_scroll is not working with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, facet-wrap, flexdashboard

I want the flex dashboard to take up the full screen (full width, full height) and scroll to fit a large number of plots in a facet wrap.  Made my issue reproducible using nycflights13, provided below and produces un-readable plots super compressed vertically.  how can I achieve this in flex dashboard?

output of knitting below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSecw.jpg

````r
---
title: "facet test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r dfs and plots, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE, cache=FALSE}

df <- flights %>%
  group_by(dest, time_hour) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

sp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=time_hour, y=n)) + geom_line()

fr <- sp + facet_wrap(~ dest)
```

```{r  facet, out.width = '100%', warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, error=TRUE}
fr
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try experimenting with the `fig.height` and `fig.width` options. This gives a fairly reasonable output for me:

````
---
title: "facet test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r dfs and plots, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE, cache=FALSE}

df <- flights %>%
  group_by(dest, time_hour) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

sp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=time_hour, y=n)) + geom_line() 

fr <- 
  sp + 
  facet_wrap(~ dest) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8))
```

```{r facet, echo=FALSE, error=TRUE, fig.height=20, fig.width=16, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
fr
```
````